# basic_string not found during linking

Tags: c++, boost, linker, wchar-t, stdstring

I am compiling in Visual Studio 10 a library developed by myself that uses Boost 1.55.0 and a third-party library, but I obtain the errors below during the linking phase.

The third-party library developer told me to recompile all the codes (my code and Boost; third-party is provided as binaries) using the flag wchar_t- to avoid to treat `wchar_t` as a type in Visual Studio. The third-pard library developer assured me to have compile its third-party library with this switch on and suggested me to recompile all the remaining code (*i.e.*, my code and Boost).
I have done this, but the errors remain.
I would like also to say that before enabling the switch wchar_t- all worked (compiling and linking) fine; the problems emerged when the third-party library has been introduced.

```
  Generating Code...
create_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::~basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "int class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > __cdecl cea::ifc::get_type(class ifc4::IfcMaterial *)'::1'::dtor$1" (?dtor$1@?0??get_type@ifc@cea@@YA?AV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@PEAVIfcMaterial@ifc4@@@Z@4HA)
create_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > &&)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QEAA@$$QEAV01@@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > __cdecl cea::ifc::get_type(class ifc4::IfcMaterial *)" (?get_type@ifc@cea@@YA?AV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@PEAVIfcMaterial@ifc4@@@Z)
create_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl Step::String::String(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (__imp_??0String@Step@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl cea::ifc::set_type(class ifc4::IfcMaterial *,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (?set_type@ifc@cea@@YAXPEAVIfcMaterial@ifc4@@AEBV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
create_helper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __cdecl std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >::compare(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)const " (__imp_?compare@?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@QEBAHAEBV12@@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl std::operator==<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> >(class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &)" (??$?8GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@1@@std@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@0@0@Z)
C:\Users\DM241428\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\cpp-ifc-model\x64\Debug\cpp-ifc-model.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Comment: `third-party is provided as binaries`  You didn't indicate what compiler this third-party library was built with.  You didn't specify what compiler options were used (except for one option), etc.  You can't just plonk in a third-party library in your app (assuming it's a static library), and not be sure it is compatible with your build.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed the third party lib developer said me that he has used Visual Studio 2010 64 bits SP1 for Windows, and that he has used the /Zcwchar_t- in order to disable the wchar_t- as types. So, according to your experience, which are the other set of infos I have to ask, in order to proceed in a safer way, to avoid problems using this 3rd party lib? I possess either the static (.lib) and dynamic (.dll) version of the library; may it help?

Comment: You need to know what runtime library setting was used to build the static library, for example, multithread-DLL, multithread, etc.  and you need to make sure your app uses the same runtime setting.  If it doesn't, then you need to change the runtime library setting and rebuild your app.

Comment: May be linker doesn't find some other libraries to link with your library? (Because of errors "unresolved external")